# Subsequent installation of MSI package of a WiX Custom Bootstrapper

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, windows-installer

I have a Wix custom bootstrapper bundled with two MSI packages:

1. pre-installer package, which needs to copy/install an executable file to a temporary folder, and
2. actual installer package

Here's the background of what I'm trying to achieve. Upon launching the bootstrapper UI, the first package should install automatically. Upon clicking "Next" button, the executable file from first package should run to update some security settings, then it has to reboot the PC to apply the changes. After reboot, the bootstrapper should proceed installing the second package. Finally, once the second package is installed, I need to uninstall the first package to clean up the temporary files.

Since the packages are in the same bundle, when the `ExecutePackage` event completes, the two of them are installed together. Is there a way to execute the first package first, then once it is installed, I will execute the second package? I tried to use `InstallCondition` variables then dynamically set them in my bootstrapper but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Much better way of asking it +1